# Web Browser não carrega link pelo método Navigate win form c#

Tags: c#, web-scraping

Boa tarde, estou fazendo um teste para criar um WebScraping no c#, porém não carrega a página no web form, apresentando o erro de javascript

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode ajudar com este erro?

Comment: Michel, tenta ajustar sua imagem pois ela está em um tamanho muito grande e acaba não sendo possível visualizar sem abrir e dar zoom.

Comment: Editado!----------

Comment: se a página carregar sem o js, habilite a propriedade de suprimir os erros de script